# How to update the rating of a user that has already rated in Firestore? Using Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function where I am implementing the rating of users. I am using a transaction to check if the user has rated before and if not i am creating a new document which has only one field - UserId.
Next time the user tries to rate the same restaurant I am not updating the rate average at all. So, how can I actually just update the rating for a user that has already rated?
Below  you can see how I am implementing the rating (if the user is rating the restaurant for the first time):

```
...
   .then(async function (doc) {
        if (doc.empty) {
            let add_clients_rating = admin.firestore().collection("restaurants_collection").doc(vendor_id).collection('ratings').doc();
            let restaurants_collection = admin.firestore().collection("restaurants_collection").doc(vendor_id);
            await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
                const restDoc = await transaction.get(restaurants_collection);

                // Compute new number of ratings
                const newNumRatings = restDoc.data().noRat + 1;

                // Compute new average rating
                const oldRatingTotal = restDoc.data().rat * restDoc.data().noRat;
                const newAvgRating = (oldRatingTotal + ratingVal) / newNumRatings;
                const round_no_rating = Math.round(newAvgRating);
               
                // create new document with user id
                transaction.set(add_clients_rating, {
                    uID: userId
                });

                // Update restaurant info
                transaction.update(restaurants_collection, {
                    rat: round_no_rating,
                    noRat: newNumRatings
                });
```

This is what I tried to implement the user's update rating:

```
   let restaurants_collection = 
   admin.firestore().collection("restaurants_collection").doc(vendor_id);
    await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
    const restDoc = await transaction.get(restaurants_collection);

    // Compute new number of ratings
    const newNumRatings = restDoc.data().noRat;

    // Compute new average rating
    const oldRatingTotal = restDoc.data().rat * restDoc.data().noRat;
    const newAvgRating = (oldRatingTotal + ratingVal) / newNumRatings;
    const round_no_rating = Math.round(newAvgRating);

    // Update restaurant info
    transaction.update(restaurants_collection, {
        rat: round_no_rating                      
    });
```

The thing I have changed here is `const newNumRatings = restDoc.data().noRat;` this line, specifically, I have removed the `+1` . But the problem is that it keeps adding new value to the rating average. So, if user1 has already rated before, when he tried to update that rating, it adds up new value. If the average is 3, and user1`s rate value is 5 it adds up to the old average (no idea how it computes it), and then when user1 updates again, the average rate it becomes larger and larger 9, 10, 11, ...

Comment: I'm unclear.  Could you edit the question to explain in more detail what this code is actually doing that's different than what you want?  What's wrong with it?

Comment: @DougStevenson the code above is working fine for the FIRST TIME rating. However, how can I update a user's rating which has already rated the same restaurant before?!

Comment: What happens when you run it the second time?  Please be specific.  Is there an error?  Does it do something different than what you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson nothing, obviously I am not doing anything to update a rating of a user that has already updated. I just dont know how to do it!

Comment: @DougStevenson tried something, please check the update.

Comment: So... I understand that you want that your users will be able to make new reviews but that the rate never changes if they have submitted a rate for the restaurant before?

The average keeps going up as you are still calculating the average and uploading it... I would first check if the document already exists (the document that only has UserId) and if it exists, I would only create the new review, and ignore the code that contains the rate calculation and updating block. this way you would just jump it over.

Comment: @LuisManuel I would like a user to be able to edit his rate. So, when he edits, the old rate should be deducted and new value should be calculated. The problem is that I am not keeping track of the value of each user rate.

Comment: So, once they set a rate, this is lost?... if that is the case it would be difficult to implement this... my idea was to take the old value, and make a method specially for updating the average: you get the new rate, you subtract the old rate from the total and add the new, and you proceed as normal to calculate the average with the total of rates... with out the old value... you won't be able to calculate the new sum of all rates as it will just end up adding up (and making the error that you have) so you would need the old value.